# Adding an account to AccountManager that is recognized by the mail application

Tags: android, email, accountmanager

Is it possible to add an IMAP or POP or some other custom account in the `AccountManager` that will be recognized by the android email application?

I noticed while adding an exchange account to the account manager that the email application automatically picked up on it (and the email just started appearing in my email application). Was wondering how it did this, and if it would work with other non-exchange accounts in the account manager.

I've tried looking through the [Email App Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email) for the point where it looks for accounts to actually see what's it doing but I cannot find it, and figured it would be easier to just ask someone more experienced with android.